# How do you Integrate ckeditor File upload and file browser capabaility

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to integrate the ckeditors file browser and upload image tools, i have managed to set the ckeditor to allow you to click on the browse file button and upload tag but how do i use ASP.NET VB to open the file browser and make the upload image work?

I am using the .NET 3.6.0 version where they provided the DLLS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Description
DotNetTextBox WYSWYG Editor Web Control For Asp.Net2.0/3.5,Open Source Version!

Demo Page:http://www.aspxcn.com.cn/dotnettextbox/default.htm(chinese language)

Ver 3.4.0 Source Code Updates:
2008/1/21
-Begin Open Source Code Today!
-Fix Insert Icq Online Icon Page Bug!
-Fix Upload File Explorer Upload File Over MaxSize Bug!
-Fix Upload File Explorer Insert URL Blank Character Bug!
-Fix Upload File Explorer Preview Images Bug!
-Fix Upload File Explorer Invalid Character Bug!
-Fix Multi-Language Load Cache Lost Bug!
-Fix FireFox Browser Url Bug!

explain:Using Vs2005 Open DotNetTextBox.Sln!

Download DotNetTextBoxV3.4.0 Source Code: [DotNetTextBox_SourceCode.rar](http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=dotnettextbox&DownloadId=26126)